# Power-BI / Dax: Count emails multiple times in a function based on the same dimension (#Order)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

**Starting Point**

A table contains two columns:

- E-Mail (string, Unique)
- Number of Orders (Integer)

Example Dataset:

```
 | E-Mail             | #Orders |
 | —————-—————-————-  |———————  |
 | user1@example.com  | 1       |
 | user2@example.com  | 1       |
 | user3@example.com  | 4       |
 | user4@example.com  | 4       |
 | user5@example.com  | 4       |
 | user6@example.com  | 5       |
 | user7@example.com  | 2       |
 | user8@example.com  | 1       |
 | user9@example.com  | 5       |
 | user10@example.com | 4       |
```

**Goal:**

A funnel analysis is to be created:
It aims to analyze how many customers (= number of unique email addresses) have

- Made at least 1 order
- Made at least 2 orders
- Made at least 3 orders

Example: Made at least 2 orders = Distinctcount (E-Mail) where #Orders >= 2

Example Chart:

[image: Bar chart]

How do I build the solution in DAX ?

Comment: Can you share some sample data and expected output? Do you want a funnel chart or just a table showing the segments?

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I have attached a dummy dataset as well as a Dummy Barchart. Hope it helps to make my challenge a little clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a calculated table where you list the label and the result :

```
MinOrdersTable = 
UNION(
    ROW("MinXOrder", "Min 1 Order", "Result", CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(OrdersTable[Email]), OrdersTable[Orders] >= 1)),
    ROW("MinXOrder", "Min 2 Orders", "Result", CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(OrdersTable[Email]), OrdersTable[Orders] >= 2)),
    ROW("MinXOrder", "Min 3 Orders", "Result", CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(OrdersTable[Email]), OrdersTable[Orders] >= 3)),
    ROW("MinXOrder", "Min 4 Orders", "Result", CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(OrdersTable[Email]), OrdersTable[Orders] >= 4)),
    ROW("MinXOrder", "Min 5 Orders", "Result", CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(OrdersTable[Email]), OrdersTable[Orders] >= 5))
)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you but this does not meet the problem. Creating a seperate function is not the deal. I want to solve it in one measure.

Comment: @Florian I updated the answer. I don't think that you can achieve what you need with only one measure at least with what you provided

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi - I think OP is looking for dynamic segmentation. https://www.daxpatterns.com/dynamic-segmentation/

Comment: @davidebacci yes maybe since his question is not clear. But imaginewe have 1000 segments with an increment of 1, the OP should review his business case.

Comment: Yes, they should probably be binned.

Comment: @davidebacci: Thank you for the link. I need to read it more then once but it help me with an other topic.